# How to calculate an angle between two lines - Conformal mapping

Tags: geometry, conformal-geometry

I have a rounded-triangle in $z$-plane that conformally mapped into unit disk in $\zeta$-plane using the Schwarz-Cristoffell method.

[image]

By definition, the conformal mapping will preserve the local angle (intersection between two lines) in the $z$-plane. In other words, the two plots should have a similar local angle between the lines.

If I have all the points to generate the two plots, how to prove that the local angle between the plots are the same?

[image]

Can someone help me on this?